# Deploying war files as SharedLibrary on weblogic Using Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, deployment, weblogic

I have a strange problem deploying war files as Shared-Library into Weblogic using Intelli-IDEA.

By using the expression **Shared-Library** I means the exact concept of shared-library that weblogic uses when you try to use the administration console for deploying a war/jar file:

[image]

Obviously my war file has no problem and when I deploy it using administration console or commandline (weblogic.Deployer) there is no problem and it is being deployed successfully.

**The problem is** I cannot make **Intellij-Idea** understand to deploy my war file as a shared-library:

[image]

I've tried to build PersonWeb artifact as jar or ear or ... but there wasn't any progress. When it is packaged in war, I can successfully deploy it as a shared library using administration console or commandline tools weblogic.Deployer.

Using commandline tool **weblogic.Deployer** and the **-library** argument you can deploy applications as shared-libraries on weblogic like this:

```
java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -username [Your username] -password [Your password] -upload -library -targets AdminServer -deploy -source [path to your war file]
```

But I couldn't find any option in intellij to pass arguments or parameters to weblogic.Deployer while deploying an artifact.

Is there any workaround to make that work using Intellij-Idea?

I'm currently using weblogic12c. But same problem raises using weblogic 11g (10.3.4 or 10.3.5)

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the edit. I want to use this opportunity to ask you this question. Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid idea weblogic plugin doesn't allow you to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that I use is:

1. Go to Weblogic console and deploy your application as the shared library. When you will be asked to specify the path, specify the path to your exploded folder (e.g. target/MyApp)
2. Go to Weblogic console and deploy all other applications and specify the path to your exploded folder (e.g. target/MyApp)
3. Remove all entries in **Deployment** tab
4. Restart the server.

You have configured all your applications and targeted them to
    exploded folder.  When you will recompile any of your applications,
    exploded folder will contain the latest version and all you need is
    to
        restart the server and WebLogic will deploy the latest version.

Comment: +1 for the workaround, didn't try it but seems to work. However, actually I was looking for an explicit way with intellij.